# Three Phase Geometry

Tags: geometry

In Electronics, a three phase system can be represented by phasors/vectors. I can solve this using an electrical simulation, but I am curious to know if a general solution can be obtained using geometry.

Start with 3 vectors (of equal magnitude) originating at the center of an equilateral triangle. The magnitude of the other vectors will be described relative to these vectors.

[image]

An unbalance in the system causes the starting point of these vectors to be moved. They are described by new vectors that originate from the new point, three end at the vertices of the original equilateral triangle. The fourth (Ic1) is the same magnitude and at right angles to vector that ends at the top (Vc1).

**Where must the new starting point be such that the sum of the 3 "I" vectors is zero.** Vectors, of course, can be summed using geometry. My answer (in brackets []) below is for the vector Vn. An answer for any of the other vectors is acceptable.

This question was inspired by this Elec Eng SE question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551340/whats-the-justification-to-determine-the-phase-sequence/551393#551393

I have attempted to use universal terms here, I apologize if I didn't.

[image]

My start at a geometric solution. The red lines form a parallelogram. My drawing is rough, I had to stretch the left Ir2 to fit.

[image]

Bonus: If the magnitude of Ic1 is not equal to the magnitude of Vc1, but can be any positive ratio, what ratio will minimize Ir3.

Comment: Your question is really not totally clear to me  but  you introduced additional vectors without explaining where they come from.  You are loading $V_{c1}$ to get the current - what about the other voltages?

Comment: With regard to the bonus - assuming $I_{R2}$ fixed than it is when $I_{R3}$ perpendicular to $I_{C1}$

Comment: For simplicity, I have assumed 1 ohm for this SE. So, Ir2 equals Vr2, and Ir3 equals Vr3 (ohms law). Ic1 = i Vc1 (capacitor has imaginary impedance, current vector is at right angle). [engineers normally use j instead of i, since i is for current]